# What Uri should be passed to an application so it can read a file (MODE_WORLD_READABLE) in internal storage of another application?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-file

I am making a widget which has an `ImageView` to display an image. I store some images in internal storage with mode as `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`. Now I need to send a `Uri` of this image so I can load the ImageView using `setImageUri`. How do I create such Uri ?

I believe this is required since a widget is handled by the home screen process.
Also, `setImageBitmap()` is not an option for me since it leads to FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION in many cases.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your uri using [Uri.fromFile(file)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29) api .

Comment: Thanks but the method you said only works for Android 2.2 and above. I found out the best to do it is this: `Uri.parse(filepath.getPath())` Your answer is correct anyway!